# How to use if else in linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have a table in which i have record of users.table have field lastLoginMonth and LastLoginYear ...i want to fetch that user who have login time more than 5 month ..but here i found two case ..
1)current year and lastLoginYear same
2)current year and lastLoginYear different
to handle this i have to use different conditions but i don't know how to handle this in query.....

```
var year = db.UserManagers.ToList();

foreach (var y in year)
{
    if (y.LastLoginYear == mydate.Year)
    {
        var modell   = (from ummm in db.UserManagers
                        where ((mydate.Month - ummm.LastLoginMonth) >5 
                            && ummm.LoginWarning==false)
                        select ummm).ToList();
                    return View(modell);

     }

     var model = (from ummm in db.UserManagers
                  where (((12 - y.LastLoginMonth) + mydate.Month) >5 
                  && ummm.LoginWarning == false)
                  select ummm).ToList();
     return View(model);
}
```

how i can organize this query in a simple way ...

Comment: What are you even doing here why do you have a foreach if your returning inside of it the first time?

Comment: I don't feel like posting an answer but you don't need a ternary you can do this using  `EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(i.FromDate, i.ToDate) > 5`

Comment: Most likely not terribly important (unless you have billions of users) but most (actually all answers as of this writing) are not [Sargable Queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: It's extremely poor practice to store information (month and year) in separate columns.  If you can, you should merge them, then the query would be much easier to write (a single where for all cases).

Comment: no actually i want to return one thing containing both data(model+modell)  but i can't make any logic through which i can solve this..so that's why i use for loop and returned two things for making understandable for you people that what exactly i wana do that ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **ternary operator**:

```
 var modell   = (from ummm in db.UserManagers
                 where (((y.LastLoginYear == mydate.Year)
                         ? ((mydate.Month - ummm.LastLoginMonth) >5) 
                         : ((12 - y.LastLoginMonth) + mydate.Month) >5)
                       && ummm.LoginWarning==false)
                 select ummm).ToList();
```

Take a look at this example to understand what does this mean like:

```
var list = new List<string> { "1", "abc", "5"};
var sel = (from s in list where ((s.Length > 1) ? true : false) select s);
```

As you can see, we take each string `s` stored in the `list` and apply to it the next filter: If it’s `Length` more then 1, we take it (as it will be where true), otherwise, we don’t take it. Thus we will take only those strings that have `Length` more then 1.

Also pay attention that you make `return` inside the `foreach` loop. That means that the `foreach` will iterate only 1 time and then will exit on the `return` you wrote. So you might expect this code to make something different from what you have written.

Comment: Thank You i have solved this  problem with your help...you explained to me very well ..Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

First approach that came to my mind could be with simple inline if:

```
var year = db.UserManagers.ToList();

        foreach (var y in year)
        {
             var model   = (from ummm in db.UserManagers
                              where (((y.LastLoginYear == mydate.Year)?(mydate.Month - ummm.LastLoginMonth):((12 - y.LastLoginMonth) + mydate.Month)) >5 && ummm.LoginWarning==false)
                              select ummm).ToList();
                return View(model);

            }
}
```

I assume that you realize that a return inside a foreach loop would make it execute only once and then return the result?

Comment: no actually i want to return one thing containing both data(model+modell)  but i can't make any logic through which i can solve this..so that's why i return two things for making understandable for you people that what exectly i wana do that ...